# ASP.net SQL Query does not filter correctly on webpage

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

When I run the query below in SQL, it works fine if I don't specify more than one parameter. But once I run this query in ASP.net to refresh the gridview it will not load the grid view unless all parameters are specified even though it is configured as "OR". So it there a way to get the gridview to load if not all parameters are filled? In sql server this query will return results if just one parameter is filled. TIA

```
Select ProjectID,Originator,Services....
FROM            dbo.tblJobs
WHERE        (ProjectName LIKE N'%' + @ProjectName + N'%') OR
                         (Originator LIKE N'%' + @Originator + N'%') OR
                         (Services LIKE N'%' + @Services + N'%') OR
                         (Brand LIKE N'%' + @Brand + N'%') OR
                         (JobDescription LIKE N'%' + @JobDescription + N'%') OR
                         (JobType LIKE N'%' + @JobType + N'%')
```

Comment: If you step through your ASP.net code are any of the values null?  If they are that could be the issue.  They may not be when running directly in SQL.  Also building a select statement like that is not advised.  You could do it much easier (and with less issues of SQL Injection) if you used a parameter Stored Procedure.

Comment: Basically the parameters are filled by textboxes on the webpage, so they are just empty. Only code I have is gridview.databind etc. Do I need to put a default NULL value in the textbox somehow?

Comment: If they are empty, then the SQL is looking for a value LIKE '%%' so looking for blank value.  Can you step through your code or build a string with the Select statement in it so you can see what it is looking for with your like statements?  Then run that in SQL directly.